# Why does it say my predicate block/3 is not called?

Tags: prolog

So I've been learning Prolog, and to test myself I wanted to solve a certain puzzle. I think I'm pretty close to solving it, but I seem to be doing something wrong. It seems my predicate `block/3` is not called.

maybe it's a syntax error, or I'm doing something that doesn't work in Prolog. I can't see it.

[image: predicate not called]

`block/3` is supposed to give all possible combinations of sets in `block/2`.

I'm not sure if it's entirely relevant but I'll include the goal of the puzzle:

> *There's four cubes, with different combination of four images on their faces. (Kim,Lab,Hail and Com)
>
>   The goal is to align the cubes in such a way that if you put them together, all the sides next to each other should be the same. So it's four of the same rows going around each cube, and then two sides that should also be matching.*

I wrote the program to just solve the rows, and disregarding the orientation of the images and the two sides. Should that give more than one answer it shouldn't give too many to manually try.

anyway, somehow `solve(X)` completely ignores my predicate `block/3`. I've been staring at it for a long time and I can't find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 member( block(1, _, Row), X )
```

is equivalent to

```
 E = block(1, _, Row), member( E, X )
```

so it does not in fact call `block/3` as a predicate, it just uses it as a compound term, symbolically.